# How to get user multiple column in Laravel Relationship?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I am using Laravel 9, I stuck into the Relationship, I have a table called `test_series_question` another is `test_series_responses`. Every `test_series_question` has one row in `test_series_responses`. I need to select the responses available in the table. Something like `WHERE question_id = '$id' AND test_id = $test_id`

I have tried to to get the responses from Laravel Model

```
function response()
{
   return $this->hasOne(TestSeriesResponse::class, 'question_id', 'id');
}
```

It's working fine, But There is a one column named `test_id` and if I dont compare test_id It'll return previously submitted responses which match the `question_id` id not the `test_id`

I have two questions

1. Can I put a parameter into `function response()` in Model from controller?
2. How can I achive the thing, Please help me out.

Here is the Controller code:

```
function testOngoing($test_id, $history_id)
{
  $test = TestSeries::find($test_id);
  $history = $history_id;
  $questions = TestSeriesQuestion::where('test_id', $test_id)->with('response')->paginate(1);
  $data = compact('test', 'questions', 'history');
  return view('test-series/test-question')->with($data);
}
```

[image: Updated Modes]

Comment: So you define the `response() function` to the`TestSeries::class()` ? then do you also define `belongsTo()` to the `TestResponse::class` ?

Comment: Actually, I just putted ```where()``` into ```response()``` function, It's works, But I don't know how to pass the ```test_id``` to the Model

Comment: Can you explain more of your problem ? and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, So basically I want the ```responses``` from  ```test_series_responses```, Now I want to add a parameter into ```Model``` from ```Controller```, I want to send the ```test_id``` from ```controller``` to ```Model``` How can I achive that?

Comment: So you want to get a specific row based on the given test_id ?

Comment: Yes, And I'm getting also, But the I want the test_id dynamic, Which will sended from controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249118/discussion-between-imdadullah-babu-and-xenooooo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
$questions = TestSeriesQuestion::with(['response' => function ($query) use ($history_id) {
    $query->where('history_id', $history_id);
}])->where('test_id', $test_id)->paginate(1)
```

Comment: It's giving an error in paginate,

Too few arguments to function App\Models\TestSeriesQuestion::response(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\scordemy\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 764 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Perfect

Note: Make sure you have to use array in the response method